# INNER JOIN with multiple tables and keys

Tags: sql-server, join, union

Well, lets start.

I have 4 servers with the same database. There is a query that works fine to get data from each DB individually. Its something like this:

```
SELECT "blablablablabla"
FROM  [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OVPM T01 with (nolock)
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..VPM2 T11 with (nolock) ON T01.UnionAll_Empresa = T11.UnionAll_Empresa and T01.DocEntry = T11.DocNum
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH6 T2 with (nolock) ON T11.UnionAll_Empresa = T2.UnionAll_Empresa and T11.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry and T11.InstId = T2.InstlmntID
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OPCH T3 with (nolock) ON T2.UnionAll_Empresa  = T3.UnionAll_Empresa and T2.DocEntry  = T3.DocEntry
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH1 T3a with (nolock) ON T3.UnionAll_Empresa = T3a.UnionAll_Empresa and T3.DocEntry = T3a.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OOCR T3b with (nolock) ON T3a.UnionAll_Empresa = T3b.UnionAll_Empresa and T3a.OcrCode2 = T3b.OcrCode
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OSLP T4 with (nolock) ON T4.UnionAll_Empresa   = T4.UnionAll_Empresa and T3.SlpCode   = T4.SlpCode  
and  T11.InvType = ''18''
AND T01.Canceled <> ''Y''
AND T01.CashSum > 0
```

Today we have one new database that merges all these 4 DBs. Each table of this new DB is a view with and Union All, with the difference that now I added a new column named "UnionAll_Empresa", to know from what server this row came from.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW AACP as
SELECT 'G8Networks Solucoes' as UnionAll_Empresa, * from SBO_G8NETWORKS_SOLUCOES.dbo.AACP
UNION All
SELECT 'G8Networks NIC' as UnionAll_Empresa, * from SBO_G8NETWORKS_NIC.dbo.AACP
UNION All
SELECT 'SPIN' as UnionAll_Empresa, * from SBO_SPIN.dbo.AACP
UNION All
SELECT 'FA2R' as UnionAll_Empresa, * from SBO_FA2R.dbo.AACP;
```

Now I need to use that old query again, with these new "tables". The problem is that now the primary keys are not unique anymore, since there are 4 servers in the same table. So the solution would be to add the "UnionAll_Empresa" field (wich tells the name of the server) as a key along with the primary keys in the query. The new query would be something like this:

```
SELECT "blalalalalala"
FROM  [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OVPM T01 with (nolock)
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..VPM2 T11 with (nolock) ON T01.DocEntry = T11.DocNum and T01.UnionAll_Empresa = T11.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH6 T2 with (nolock) ON  T11.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry and T11.InstId = T2.InstlmntID and T11.UnionAll_Empresa = T2.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OPCH T3 with (nolock) ON  T2.DocEntry  = T3.DocEntry and T2.UnionAll_Empresa  = T3.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH1 T3a with (nolock) ON T3.DocEntry = T3a.DocEntry and T3.UnionAll_Empresa = T3a.UnionAll_Empresa
LEFT JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OOCR T3b with (nolock) ON  T3a.OcrCode2 = T3b.OcrCode and T3a.UnionAll_Empresa = T3b.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OSLP T4 with (nolock) ON  T3.SlpCode   = T4.SlpCode and T4.UnionAll_Empresa   = T4.UnionAll_Empresa
WHERE T11.InvType = ''18''
AND T01.Canceled <> ''Y''
AND T01.CashSum > 0
```

But it shows an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

It stills find multiple results for some primary key, even when I add the comparison with the column "UnionAll_Empresa" (the name of the original server).

Am I doing something wrong?

--- Here is the full query

```
set @vQuery = '
SELECT   --Pagametos de NF em dinheiro 
T01.UnionAll_Empresa,
Base = ''' + @database + ''', 
NomeEmp = (select a.CompnyName from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OADM a with (nolock)),
CNPJ = (select a.TaxIdNum from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..oadm a with (nolock)),
IE = (Select TaxIdNum2 from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OADM with (nolock)),
Filial = (Select PrintHeadr from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OADM with (nolock)),
Proj = isnull(T3.Project,''''),
OcrCode2 = isnull(T3a.OcrCode2,''0''),
OcrName = isnull(T3b.OcrName,''Sem projeto definido''),
''NF'' TipoDoc,
''DIN'' Tipo,
T01.CardCode, 
T01.CardName,
CardFName = (select CardFName from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OCRD with (nolock) where OCRD.CardCode = T01.CardCode and OCRD.UnionAll_Empresa = T01.UnionAll_Empresa),
T01.DocEntry CodigoBaixaPagamento,
T11.DocEntry NumeroSapDocumento,
T01.DocDate DataDocBaixa,
T3.DocDate,
T11.InstId Parcela,
'''' SituacaoParc,
''1900-01-01'' DataUltBaixa,
T11.InvType,
T2.InsTotal ValorDaParcelaOriginal,
T01.DocDate DataLancamentoBaixa,
T2.DueDate VencimentoOriginalParcela,
T3.SeqCode,
SerieNF = (select SeqName from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..NFN1 with (nolock) where SeqCode = T3.SeqCode and UnionAll_Empresa = T3.UnionAll_Empresa),
T3.Series,
T3.Serial,
T3.SlpCode,
T4.SlpName,
round((T3a.LineTotal/T3.DocTotal)*(T11.SumApplied/T01.DocTotal)*(T01.CashSum),2) ValorPago,
T01.DocTotal TotalBaixa,
T01.CashSum TotalDinBaixa,
T01.TrsfrSum TotalTransfBaixa,
T01.[CheckSum] TotalCHBaixa,
T01.BoeSum TotalBoeBaixa,
T01.CreditSum TotalCCredBaixa,
Case 
When T01.CashSum   > 0 Then ''Dinheiro''
When T01.TrsFrSum  > 0 Then ''Transferência''
When T01.CreditSum > 0 Then ''Cartao''
End TipoDocumento,
'''' NossoNumBol,
'''' DigNossoNumBol,
''1900-01-01'' VencBoleto,
'''' CodBancoBol,
'''' NomeBancoBol,
0 VlrTotBol,
'''' NomeFPagtoBol,
'''' LinhaDigBol,
'''' TrsfrRef,
'''' NumCH,
'''' DataCH,
'''' StatusCH,
0 VlrTotCH,
'''' BancoCH,
'''' AgenciaCH,
'''' ContaCH,
'''' BoeStatus,
'''' CodCCred,
'''' NomeCCred,
'''' NumComprCartao,
0 NumParcCartao,
''1900-01-01'' PrimVencimentoCartao,
0 VlrTotCartao,
VlrDin = round((T3a.LineTotal/T3.DocTotal)*(T11.SumApplied/T01.DocTotal) * T01.CashSum,2),
VlrTransf = 0,
VlrCredit = 0,
VlrBol = 0,
VlrCH = 0,
VlrCart = 0,
VlrDev = 0,
VlrBLI = 0
FROM  [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OVPM T01 with (nolock)
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..VPM2 T11 with (nolock) ON T01.DocEntry = T11.DocNum and T01.UnionAll_Empresa = T11.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH6 T2 with (nolock) ON  T11.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry and T11.InstId = T2.InstlmntID and T11.UnionAll_Empresa = T2.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OPCH T3 with (nolock) ON  T2.DocEntry  = T3.DocEntry and T2.UnionAll_Empresa  = T3.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..PCH1 T3a with (nolock) ON T3.DocEntry = T3a.DocEntry and T3.UnionAll_Empresa = T3a.UnionAll_Empresa
LEFT JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OOCR T3b with (nolock) ON  T3a.OcrCode2 = T3b.OcrCode and T3a.UnionAll_Empresa = T3b.UnionAll_Empresa
INNER JOIN [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OSLP T4 with (nolock) ON  T3.SlpCode   = T4.SlpCode and T4.UnionAll_Empresa   = T4.UnionAll_Empresa
WHERE T11.InvType = ''18''
AND T01.Canceled <> ''Y''
AND T01.CashSum > 0
'
exec ('insert into #RelContasPagar ' + @vQuery)
```

Comment: I don't se a subquery in queries listed. There must be one in select list somewhere. Could you please expand "blabla..."?

Comment: There it is. I was thinking that the problem could be in the joins. Whenever i find a join or a "where" clause, i add the "UnionAll_Empresa" comparsion, to avoid inconsistent primary keys, but i'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something Wrong?

Here's a problem in one of your join conditions:

```
and T4.UnionAll_Empresa   = T4.UnionAll_Empresa
```

T4 to T4!

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I was getting crazy with this query. Thank you, and everybody that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I really feel this question is beyond me but I'll propose something we're doing on a data warehouse project I'm working on.  In addition to the standard ID primary key that we have on each table, in a number of cases we've added an additional key that we call the BK (Business Key) that we try to ensure is unique.  The usage is a little different from a standard ID key because the BK is a string that has business related information embedded in it.  I could see you using it to have a 'pseudo' primary key that could also tell you which server was the source for the row of data you've retrieved.

This may seem lame but it's all I could come up with.

Comment: I'm in a difficult situation. The database is from a SAP system, with more than 1000 tables. And this query is from an old employe, used to generate some reports. Now they want to generate one single report for all bases, and they dont have time for an DW approach.

So All I was able to do so far is to create a new DB with views of these 1000 tables, making unnions and adding a new collum to at least tell from what server each row is.

I dont know if my logic is correct, but i was thinking that just adding this new collum in all comparsions I could convert this query to the new DB... =/